# Attribute Error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'

Tags: python, django, django-models, web

I have reached till chapter 4 of the Mozilla Django tutorial, but then I met with this error. I followed everything as it said but it is giving me this error when I tried to open the ***BookInstance*** model from the admin panel :

> AttributeError at /admin/catalog/bookinstance/ 'NoneType' object has
>   no attribute 'id'

Here is my code, **models.py**( I've highlighted the part where the error occurs) :

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class Book(models.Model):
    """
    Model representing a book (but not a specific copy of a book).
    """
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.ForeignKey('Author', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
      # Foreign Key used because book can only have one author, but authors can have multiple books
      # Author as a string rather than object because it hasn't been declared yet in file.
    summary = models.TextField(max_length=1000, help_text="Enter a brief description of the book")
    isbn = models.CharField('ISBN',max_length=13, help_text='13 Character <a href="https://www.isbn-international.org/content/what-isbn">ISBN number</a>')
    genre = models.ManyToManyField(Genre, help_text="Select a genre for this book")
      # ManyToManyField used because Subject can contain many books. Books can cover many subjects.
      # Subject declared as an object because it has already been defined.

    def display_genre(self):
        """
        Creates a string for the Genre. This is required to display genre in Admin.
        """
        return ', '.join([ genre.name for genre in self.genre.all()[:3] ])
        display_genre.short_description = 'Genre'


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """
        Returns the url to access a particular book instance.
        """
        return reverse('book-detail', args=[str(self.id)])

    def __str__(self):
        """
        String for representing the Model object.
        """
        return self.title



import uuid # Required for unique book instances

class BookInstance(models.Model):
    """
    Model representing a specific copy of a book (i.e. that can be borrowed from the library).
    """
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, help_text="Unique ID for this particular book across whole library")
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    imprint = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    due_back = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

    LOAN_STATUS = (
        ('d', 'Maintenance'),
        ('o', 'On loan'),
        ('a', 'Available'),
        ('r', 'Reserved'),
    )

    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=LOAN_STATUS, blank=True, default='d', help_text='Book availability')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["due_back"]


    def __str__(self):
        """
        String for representing the Model object
        """
        ***return '%s (%s)' %(self.id,self.book.title)***
```

Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT : HERE IS THE COMPLETE ERROR
[image: Click here to view the error]

EDIT: fixed it

I replaced it with

```
        return str('%s (%s)'% (self.id, self.book.title))
```

Comment: Are you sure the BookInstance model in properly reflected in DB while doing migration?

Comment: @AbijithMg,
Yeah, I've migrated everything.

Comment: Post the complete stack trace of the error in your Q.

Comment: Also refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949252/python-attribute-error-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-something

Comment: I've edited according to your request. Also I've referred to the link that you provided but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: The error message in the screenshot is different than the one in your question title. Also, don't post screenshots but paste and format the error text within the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)` here you have added `null=True` and in the `__str__` method you are adding `self.book.title`, Assuming if `self.book` is None, so it will fail to get `self.book.title`.

And also you are misssing '(' closing parenthesis here `return '%s (%s)' %(self.id,self.book.title)`

Add a if condition to check if `self.book` is not None.

```
    def __str__(self):
        """
        String for representing the Model object
        """
        if self.book:
            return '%s (%s)' %(self.id, self.book.title))
        else:
            return '%s (%s)' %(self.id, self.imprint)) # add some other value that you want here
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your screenshot!

In your **admin.py** you might have mentioned **title** as a field for **BookInstance** but that is not defined in your model definition so the error occurs.

Comment: Nah, I have defined everything. 
When I changed it to :         
return str('%s (%s)'% (self.id, self.book.title)), it worked.

Comment: Ok cool. If at all my answer helped and u got it working then accept the answer and close it.